# Flutter provider not working in release apk and profile mode, but working fine in debug mode

Tags: flutter, provider, consumer

The provider works to provide real time updates to consumers but only works in debug mode and not release mode and profile mode.
Anyone has this issue ?
Thank you very much !!!